# Confused about passing data between server and client in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm having trouble understanding the correct way of handling data exchange between server-side and client-side components in NextJS 13.

I'm trying to understand this by creating the simplest scenario possible. I have these two functions that simply read and write JSON files on the server:

```js
import fs from 'fs'

export const saveData = async (data) => {
  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)
  try {
    await fs.promises.writeFile('data/data.json', jsonData)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err)
  }
}

export const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonData = await fs.promises.readFile('data/data.json')
    const data = JSON.parse(jsonData)
    return data

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err)
    return null
  }
}
```

A React component that displays the data:

```js
export const SomeComponent = ({ data }) => <p>{data.someKey}</p>
```

And an interactive React component that gets user input:

```js
'use client'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Input({ handleInput }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick={() => handleInput(value)}>Save</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If I create a page function to get the data and handle saving new data, I cannot pass the handler to the Input component, because it's a client-side component.

```js
import { SomeComponent } from './components/component'
import { getData, saveData } from './data'
import Input from './components/input'

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getData()

  const handleInput = (data) => {
    saveData(data)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SomeComponent data={data} />
      {/* Error: */}
      <Input handleInput={handleInput}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How, then, is passing data between the client and the server supposed to be handled in this example?

Answer (score 4):

You basically have two options when it comes to this problem:

1. **Option 1**: An API that can be called from the client component which updates the file and optimistically updating the local state. Probably the more common approach to this kind of requirement.
2. **Option 2**: A server action that which passed to the client component in combination with the new `useOptimistic` hook. Keep in mind that server actions are still in alpha and not recommended to use in production yet.

I strongly recommend you check the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions) about the limitations and specification of server actions. Here is a simple example what the second option may look like if implemented:

###### Your server component

```
const onSave = async (update: any) => {
  "use server";
  const { default: fs } = await import("fs"); 
  await fs.writeJSON("./myfile.json", update);
}

async function ServerComponent(): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const data = await getMyData();
  return <ClientComponent data={data} onSave={onSave} />;
}
```

The `use server` directive is used to define the function as a server action. Keep in mind that server actions do not respect sessions by default and the same function is ran for each request.

###### Your client component

```
function ClientComponent(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { data: initialData, onSave } = props;
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

  const onUpdate = useCallback(async (update: any) => {
    setData(prev => ({ ...prev, ...update }));
    await onSave(update);
  }, [onSave]);

  return // ...
}
```

You will have to activate server actions inside your next config file due to their current alpha state, otherwise this example will not work.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand you correctly, even if I'm not using any external backend and just want to read and write files based on user input, I should implement a barebones custom API just for this purpose?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean, yes. You can call the API handler logic directly from the server component by defining your  logic separately and importing it into your server component and API. Making it reusable.